# exp function in Julia evaluating to 0

Tags: julia, mpfr

I want to calculate and plot the probability density of a wave function in Julia. I wrote a small snippet of Julia code for evaluating the following function:

[image: P = A^2 e^{-(\sqrt(Cm)/\hbar)x^2}]

The Julia (incomplete) code is:

```
set_bigfloat_precision(100)
A = 10
C = 5
m = BigFloat(9.10938356e-31)
ℏ = BigFloat(1.054571800e-34)
t = exp(-(sqrt(C * m) / ℏ))
```

The last line where I evaluate `t` gives `0.000000000000...`. I tried to set the precision of the BigFloat as well. No luck! What am I doing wrong? Help appreciated.

Comment: The square root in your formula is a bit ambiguous. It looks to me like it is supposed to go over both numerator and denominator of the fraction. But in your code, you're only taking the square root of the numerator... is this the issue?

Comment: Note that normally you wouldn't want to use something like `m = BigFloat(9.10938356e-31)`. `9.10938356e-31` is a Float64, it will round off, and then turn into a BigFloat, but you will have already induced the Float64 roundoff error there. Instead, it's usually more robust to use `parse(BigFloat,"9.10938356e-31")`. I don't think that's your error here (because you put in the decimal), but it may stop some error in the near future.

Comment: @ColinTBowers Turns out you were right about the square root. Edited. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I did the necessary changes suggested by you. As pointed out by Colin, I had misread the wave equation. I had to take the square root of the entire fraction - not only the numerator. The problem went away. Now I'm facing another issue. I am using Gadfly to plot the values of P, but I don't think Gadfly likes large numbers. It doesn't plot anything- just shows this "At least one finite value must be provided to formatter.". Any suggestions?

Comment: It likely converts to Float64s to plot. I would try the Plotly backend via Plots.jl. I have had good luck using that for plotting really small (1e-48) Bigs. Another thing to try is scaling the equation by dividing by a large value, and scaling the axes as well to compensate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While in comments Chris Rackauckas has pointed out you entered the formula wrong. I figured it was interesting enough to answer the question anyway

Lets break it down so we can see what we are raising:

```
A = 10
C = 5
m = BigFloat(9.10938356e-31)
h = BigFloat(1.054571800e-34)

z = -sqrt(C * m)/h
t = exp(z)
```

So
`z =-2.0237336022083455711032042949257e+19` 
so very roughly `z=-2e19)`

so roughly `t=exp(-2e19)`  (ie `t=1/((e^(2*10^19))`)
That is a very small number.

Consider that 
`exp(big"-1e+10") = 9.278...e-4342944820`
and
`exp(big"-1e+18") = 2.233...e-434294481903251828`

and yes, julia says: 
`exp(big"-2e+19) = 0.0000`

`exp(big"-2e+19)` is a very small number.
That puts us in context I hope. Very small number.

---

So julia depends on [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) for BigFloats
You can try [MPFR online](http://ex-cs.sist.ac.jp/~tkouya/cgi-bin/try_mpfr.cgi). At precision 8192, `exp(-2e10)=0`
So same result.

Now, it is not the precision that we care about.
But rather the range of the exponant.

MPFR use something kinda like IEEE style floats, where precision is the length of the mantissa, and then you have a exponent. `2^exponent * mantissa`

So there is a limit on the range of the exponent.

See: [MPFR docs:](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#index-mpfr_005fget_005femin)

> Function: mpfr_exp_t mpfr_get_emin (void)
>   Function: mpfr_exp_t mpfr_get_emax (void)
>
> Return the (current) smallest and largest exponents allowed for a floating-point variable. **The smallest positive value of a floating-point variable is one half times 2 raised to the smallest exponent** and the largest value has the form (1 - epsilon) times 2 raised to the largest exponent, where epsilon depends on the precision of the considered variable.

Now julia does set these to there maximum range the fairly default MPFR compile will allow. I've been digging around the MPFR source trying to find where this is set, but can't find it. I believe it is related to the max fault a Int64 can hold.

`Base.MPFR.get_emin() = -4611686018427387903 =typemin(Int64)>>1 + 1`

You can adjust this but only up.

So anyway

`0.5*big"2.0"^(Base.MPFR.get_emin()) = 8.5096913117408361391297879096205e-1388255822130839284`

but 
`0.5*big"2.0"^(Base.MPFR.get_emin()-1) = 0.00000000000...`

---

Now we know that

`exp(x) = 2^(log(2,e)*x)`

So we can `exp(z) = 2^(log(2,e)*z)`

`log(2,e)*z          = -29196304319863382016`
`Base.MPFR.get_emin() = -4611686018427387903`

So since the exponent (rough -2.9e19)  is less than the minimum allowed exponent (roughly -4.3e17).
**An underflow occurs.**

Thus your answer as to why you get zero.

It may (or may not) be possible to recomplile MPFR with Int128 exponents, but julia hasn't.

Perhaps julia should throw a Underflow exception.
Free encouraged to report that as an issue on the Julia Bug Tracker.

Comment: You explained it very elegantly. Thank you very kindly! Plus I opened an issue on git - [Underflow should occur when evaluating exp for very small numbers](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17893)